# power bi: how to establish correct connection between 2 tables

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I created 2 tables (B and C) from table A. See attached picture:
[image]

The connection I established:

```
'one' in table C: concatenate Name + yr + month (which gives unique values in table C) 
'to many' in table B
```

doesn't give me a desirable result.

When I click a number on the table C (highlighted with yellow), it filters the values in table B.
But when I click on a number in table B (highlighted with yellow), it doesn't filter.

Would you help me to left only one row in table C (with information about John) by clicking the number in table B.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of division the initial table on two in Query Editor, I created 2 matrixes on the basis of the initial table. Then, the correct relationships between 2 tables were created.